# ajax call in javascript not returning items to correct lists

Tags: javascript, ajax, list

I am a student and am having an issue getting information on the correct lists.   My sample data has a male runner and a female runner.  I have three lists of runners:  male, female, all.   When I run my code, nothing appears on the male and female lists but all do show up on the "all" list.    What modification do I need to get the runners on the appropriate gender lists?

```
function getXMLRacers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "finishers.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            // Empty lists to prevent duplication.
            $("#finishers_m").empty();
            $("#finishers_f").empty();
            $("#finishers_all").empty();

            // Place runner name on appropriate lists.
            $(xml).find("runner").each(function () {
                var info = "<li>Name: " + $(this).find("fname").text() + " " +
                    $(this).find("lname").text() + ".  Time: " + $(this).find("time").text() + "</li>";
                if ($(this).find("gender").text === "m") {
                    $("#finishers_m").append(info);
                } else if ($(this).find("gender").text === "f") {
                    $("#finishers_f").append(info);
                } else { }
                $("#finishers_all").append(info);
            });
            getTime();
        }
    });
};
```

My sample data in an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<finishers>
    <runner>
      <fname>John</fname>
      <lname>Smith</lname> 
      <gender>m</gender>
      <time>25:31</time> 
    </runner>
    <runner>
      <fname>Jane</fname>
      <lname>Smith</lname> 
      <gender>f</gender>
      <time>26:01</time> 
    </runner>
</finishers>
```

My html file where the lists are defined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>NTC Race Finishers</title> 
        <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <header> 
            <h2>NTC Race Finishers!</h2> 
        </header> 
        <div id="main"> 
            <ul class="idTabs"> 
                <li><a href="#male">Male Finishers</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#female">Female Finishers</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#all">All Finishers</a></li> 
            </ul> 
            <div id="male"> 
                <h4>Male Finishers</h4> 
                <ul id="finishers_m"></ul>
            </div> 
            <div id="female"> 
                <h4>Female Finishers</h4> 
                <ul id="finishers_f"></ul>
            </div> 
            <div id="all"> 
                <h4>All Finishers</h4> 
                <ul id="finishers_all"></ul>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <footer>
            <h4>Congratulations to all our finishers!</h4>  
            <button id="btnStart">Start Page Updates</button>   
            <button id="btnStop">Stop Page Updates</button>
            <br>
            <span id="freq"></span>
            <br><br>
            Last Updated: <div id="updatedTime"></div>
        </footer>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="scripts/jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.    When calling the text function within the following if statement, I failed to add () after the word text.   The correct code is:

```
if ($(this).find("gender").text() === "m") {
                    $("#finishers_m").append(info);
                } else if ($(this).find("gender").text() === "f") {
                    $("#finishers_f").append(info);
                } else { }
                $("#finishers_all").append(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

@DJB I think the problem lies somewhere within the following code

```
 if ($(this).find("gender").text === "m") {
                    $("#finishers_m").append(info);
                } else if ($(this).find("gender").text === "f") {
                    $("#finishers_f").append(info);
                } else { }
```

try changing code so that you are not dependent on `$(this).find("gender").text` then try debugging from there. If you can provide more information than stackoverflow will be more helpful.